# help with DDclient config

Tags: dns, ddclient

I'm try to update my IP to Cloudflare.
What I done so far :

```
sudo apt-get install ddclient libjson-any-perl
cd ~ wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ddclient/ddclient/ddclient-3.8.3.tar.bz2 tar -jxvf ddclient-3.8.3.tar.bz2 sudo cp -f ddclient-3.8.3/ddclient /usr/sbin/ddclient
sudo mv /etc/ddclient.conf /etc/ddclient
```

however when I'm trying

```
sudo nano /etc/ddclient/ddclient.conf
```

I have an error message "Path '/etc/ddclient' is not a directory"

Comment: What version Ubuntu? Why did you install ddclient from sourceforge? It should have already been installed. It's in the Ubuntu repos. And you incorrectly renamed /etc/ddclient.conf to /etc/ddclient.

Answer (score 0):

sudo mv /etc/ddclient.conf /etc/ddclient does not create a new directory named ddclient and place ddclient.conf within it.  Instead, it renames 'ddclient.conf' to 'ddclient'

You can access this file with sudo nano /etc/ddclient

Alternatively, if you want to move this within a new subdirectory, run sudo mv /etc/ddclient.conf /etc/ddclient/ddclient.conf instead.